# Haskell what does following function do?

Tags: haskell

I am quite new to haskell but fortunately I need to implement just a few functions.
I do have questions about the following function

```
next :: Eq a => [a] -> a ->  a
next l@(x:_) e = case dropWhile (/= e) l of
                   (_:y:_) -> y
                   _ -> x
```

- What does `l@` do?
- What does `dropWhile (/= e) l of` stand for, especially the `/=` operator
- What does `of` mean in this context?
- What does `(_:y:_)` do? I know `(x:xs)` will allow you to grab head or tail but what is in `y` variable?
- What will the arrow do? `_ -> x`

Comment: I don't know how the course (?) is organized, but if this is one of the first examples, then the course should probably restructured a bit, since it introduces too much concepts at once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All good questions!

> - What does `l@` do?

That's called an *as-pattern*. It gives a name to a whole pattern. `l@(x:_)` is a pattern which matches a list with at least one element. It name the head of the list `x`, discards the tail of the list, and names the whole list (that is, the value of the expression `x:_`) `l`.

> - What does `dropWhile (/= e) l of` stand for, especially the `/=` operator

`/=` is how Haskell spells "not equal". It's the same as `!=` in eg Java. The syntax `(/= e)`, where an infix operator is given one argument in parentheses, is called a *section*. It stands for `(\x -> x /= e)`. So `dropWhile (/= e) l` drops elements from `l` as long as they don't equal `e`.

> - What does `of` mean in this context?

It's just part of the `case` expression syntax. It separates the scrutinee from the branches:

```
case foo of
    bar -> ...
    baz -> ...
    ...
```

> - What does `(_:y:_)` do? I know `(x:xs)` will allow you to grab head or tail but what is in `y` variable?

That's just a more complex pattern. In this instance it's matching lists with at least two elements and naming the second element `y`.

`x:xs` separates the head from the tail; `x:(y:ys)` separates the first two elements from the rest. Since `(:)` is right-associative, you can drop the parentheses (`x:y:ys`), and the `_`s just mean "I'm not interested in this".

> - What will the arrow do? `_ -> x`

Again, it's just part of the `case` expression syntax. It separates patterns from return values. In this case the pattern is a catch-all wildcard pattern and the return value is `x`.

---

To summarise: this function is supposed to look for `e` in `l` and return the following element. That said, it's not an especially great implementation of that idea. I spy two particular problems.

1. It'll fail with an exception (and crash your program!) if the input list is empty, because there's no clause for the `[]` case in `next`'s declaration. `next` is a *partial* function.
2. If `dropWhile (/= e) l` doesn't return a list with at least two elements (so that the `_:y:_` pattern doesn't match), it'll return `x`, the first element of the list. (This could happen if `e` is missing from the list or if it's the last element.) This seems like a very strange thing to do.

I'd probably fix it by accounting for the possibility that there may not even be a `next` element of `l`. `e` could be the last element of `l`, or it might not be in `l` at all. This is a fundamental part of the meaning of this function, not just a bug in the implementation, so we should account for it in the type.

```
next :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Maybe a
```

By giving `next` a return type of `Maybe a`, I'm indicating that it might not return anything.

```
next l e = case dropWhile (/= e) l of
                (_:x:_) -> Just x
                _ -> Nothing
```

So this implementation says: if `dropWhile (/= e) l` returns a list of at least two elements, return the second one. (I'm using `Just :: a -> Maybe a` to wrap the value into a `Maybe`.) Otherwise return `Nothing` at all.

Don't worry too much about this, but for what it's worth, we can make this function slightly shorter using one of Haskell's more advanced features. The `ViewPatterns` language extension is designed to simplify functions like this one which just perform `case` analysis on a secondary value.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
next :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a  -- I've flipped the arguments
next e (dropWhile (/= e) -> _:x:_) = Just x
next _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: this question was asked 11 min ago, 3 min ago we have awesome answer :)

Comment: @GeorgeMorris see my edit, I've fixed a couple of bugs in your original function :)